# IOS UiTableView Cells how can I make it's height adjustable

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboard

I am using a TableView and have a TableViewCell this is my first time creating one successfully. I am getting Data via Json and populating the TableView; my issue is that all TableView Cells have the same height and since the data that I am getting back varies in size it leads to some bad looking tables Cells. For instance look at the image below how can I make it so that the TableView Cell expands if there is more data like the first cell below shows or contract if it's less data like the 2nd cell below so that there isn't so much white space shown.

[image]

This is how the StoryBoard looks and the element that can sometimes have a lot of data is the **Post** Button-label shown below . I essentially am trying to do 2 things: Expand the TableViewCell if the Post-Data is long or make the TableViewCell smaller if the Post-data is small.

[image]

and I have access to all elements

```
    class HomePageTVC: UITableViewCell {



    @IBOutlet weak var profile_id: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var comment: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var vote: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var time: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var post: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var fullname: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var location: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        profile_id.isHidden = true
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
      //  post.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step1 :**
Apply the constraints as shown,

[image]

Textual representation of constraints shown in image below are :)

Vertical Constraints :
V:|-[8]-[Full Name]-[8]-[time]-[8]-[TextView]-[8]-|

No height constraints on any of the component.
On applying these constraints xCode will suggest you to modify the **Content Compression Resistance Priority** to **749** Do it !

**Step 2** : uncheck the textView scrollable property

**Step 3** : Set the number of lines to 0

**Step 4** : In your tableView controller's ViewDidLoad() write

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
```

**Step 5** : Don't write **heightForRowAtIndexPath** delegate :)

Thats all :)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sandeep's answer, you should calculate the cell height before they are being displayed, in order to prevent some lagging scrolling experience.

```
@interface SomeTableViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *cellHeightsDictionary;

@end

@implementation SomeTableViewController

- (NSMutableDictionary *)cellHeightsDictionary { //setter
    if (!_cellHeightsDictionary) {
        _cellHeightsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    }
    return _cellHeightsDictionary;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSIndexPath *key = indexPath;
    NSNumber *height = @(cell.frame.size.height);
    //store the pre-calculated cell height and index path to the dictionary
    [self.cellHeightsDictionary setObject:height forKey:key];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSNumber *height = [self.cellHeightsDictionary objectForKey:indexPath];

    if (height) { //load the height from dictionary for this index path
        return height.floatValue;
    }

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

@end
```